# seed.js - Kriskowal Q won't resolve promise? Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I have a problem with my angular project and seed.js. I've prepared date, but i have a relationship in my data between Category and Product. I need to get created Category object, so i wrote a function:

```
function getCategory(name) {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  var promise = Category.findOne({'name': name}).exec();
  deferred.resolve(promise);
  console.log(promise);
  console.log(deferred.promise);
}
```

but I'm getting:

```
Promise {
  emitter: 
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined },
  emitted: {},
  ended: false }
{ state: 'pending' }
```

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

If you resolve a promise with another promise, the first one stays in the pending state until the second one resolves.
But don't worry, it is attached, and you can make sure by using the `then` function to subscribe to the promise resolution:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();

// var promise = Category.findOne({'name': name}).exec();
var promise = new Promise(resolve => { // imitating an asynchronous task, like exec()
  setTimeout(() => resolve('#1'), 1);
});
deferred.resolve(promise);

console.log(promise); // logs: Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
console.log(deferred.promise.inspect()); // logs: Object {state: "pending"}
deferred.promise.then(x => { console.log(x); }, e => { console.error(e); }); // Prints "#1" after the promise resolves
```

By the way, I don't see a reason why to do this. [MongooseJS's exec function already returns a standard promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec), you esentially just copy that one.

Comment: Wait a minute. I'm running into forrest but i don't know why ;) Meybe i start over. I have two collections One is Category, second is Book Now i need to link Book document to Category document. In model i've used: 
category: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category'
  },

Now i need to resolve selected category promise and input there category._id; Meybe is there a simplest way to do this?

Comment: Could you please update your question with this new information? And it would be helpful if you provided more code to see what went wrong.